# Is there a way to filter results in the attribute table of a point shapefile by the extent of a second polygon shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, filter, spatial-filter

I am currently trying to temporarly filter data with in the attribute table to a confined area defined by a second polygon shapefile. The data set to be filtered consists of 100s of points that extent outside the areas I am intrested in. I have multiple seperate area that I am examining so would prefer not to clip data multiple times for each individual area. Is there a way to simply filter by an expression in the field calculator using the second polygon as the area extent?

I am using QGIS v.3.14.0

Comment: You simply could join some ID from the polygons to the points and filter using this ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Processing Toolbox is an algorithm "select by location" which pretty much does what you are asking for!

[image]

An in depth- description of how to use this can be found here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html?highlight=select%20location#select-by-location

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect and so simple